# how to get something back from a php file using jQuery?

Tags: php, jquery, post, get

i am sending some value to a php file like this:

```
$.post('php/xxx.php', { username: userName } );
```

and the php file echo'es out a var `$test`

how can i get it back into the js?

i was thinking to use this:

```
var get_back = $.get('php/xxx.php', ... );
```

but i am not sure how...

thanks

edit:

here is my php file:

```
    include("connect.php");
$get_username = $_POST['username'];
$username = '';
$username = mysql_real_escape_string($get_username);
echo $get_username;

$result = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT username FROM database WHERE username='$username' LIMIT 1"));
    if($result !== FALSE) {
        echo $username;
    }
```

i want to get back this `echo $username;` value

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The various ajax functions in jQuery ([`ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax), [`post`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/), [`get`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get)) accept callback functions where you can handle the returned data:

```
//define username outside so that 
//it's available outside of the scope 
//of the callback function
var username; 
$.post('php/xxx.php', 
       { username: userName }, 
       function(data){
            //per the comment below, 
            //assuming data will simply 
            //be the username
            username = data;
       });
```

Comment: `data` being whatever is returned from the php file?

Comment: Yes (you could rename it to whatever else makes sense but `data` is common). The exact format of the data will depend on what's being returned by the server - jQuery will try to automatically detect and parse JSON, XML, HTML or text so that you get an object that you can without having to parse it yourself. For more details, take a look at the `dataType` parameter in the call to `ajax` or `post` or `get`. In your case, it sounds like it might be plain text so it'll be a string object.

Comment: let's say that in the php file i return `echo $username;`. how do i get that back into jquery?

Comment: if `var userName = 'test';` then i get back 'testtest'   , hmmm

Comment: Could you edit your question and post updated code showing what exactly you're doing now?

Comment: According to your latest code, you're `echo`ing at two places which is why you see `testest`. Get rid of the `echo get_username`

Comment: Thanks, I guess! You can be sure I didn't mean to be hilarious :)